# i have product collection and i want perform search, and filter according to category

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules, nodes

```
export const getTestProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let search = req.query.search;
    let category = req.query.category;

    let categoryQry = category ? category : {};

    let query = search
      ? {
          $or: [
            { name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i" } },
            { description: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i" } },
          ],
        }
      : {};

    const products = await productModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "categories", // Name of the collection to join
            localField: "category",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category", // Output field that will contain the joined data
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $or:[
              {"category.name": categoryQry},
              {$and: [query, { isDeleted: false }]},
            ],
            
          },
        },
      ])
      .then((product) => {
        res.status(200).json({
          products: product,
          message: "product fetched",
          Total: product.length,
          status: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: error.message,
          status: false,
        });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message,
      status: false,
    });
  }
};`
```

this is my getproduct controller. inside this i want to search in name, description based on user query, if user perform search query then search has to be done or if user write ?category="some" then product will fetch accordingly. here category is coming from different collection so i used $lookup.

but category wise filter are not working...

i want category wise data when user write category in query in url (like this: http://localhost:8001/products?category=mobile) and if user provide search query then want to perform search.. and if user not providing anything then all the product should be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in matching the `category`, Try this :

````
export const getTestProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let search = req.query.search;
    let category = req.query.category;

    let query = search
      ? {
          $or: [
            { name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i" } },
            { description: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: "i" } },
          ],
        }
      : {};

      const match = category ? {
        $or:[
          {"category.name":  { $regex: `.*${category}.*`, $options: "i" } }, // category},
          {$and: [query, { isDeleted: false }]},
        ],
        
      } : {
        $or:[
          {$and: [query, { isDeleted: false }]},
        ],
        
      }
    const products = await productModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "categories", // Name of the collection to join
            localField: "category",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category", // Output field that will contain the joined data
          },
        },
        {
          $match: match,
        },
      ])
      .then((product) => {
        res.status(200).json({
          products: product,
          message: "product fetched",
          Total: product.length,
          status: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: error.message,
          status: false,
        });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message,
      status: false,
    });
  }
};```
````

Comment: Thank you for answering my question quickly !
But problem is it shows data, containing other categories too. like below

and i use unwind to unwrap the category from array. but still i facing issue in it.

````{
"_id": "64633207fb3aad3de44b8c7d",
"product_id": "44",
"name": "Ladies Multicolored Dress",
"description": "This classy shirt for women gives you a gorgeous look on everyday wear and specially for semi-casual wears.",
"category": {
"_id": "645e17d103256fc90fb59ecc",
"name": "tops",
"status": true,
},
"platform": "amazon",
"isDeleted": false,
},````